# DynamoDB query using secondary index, how to query with different keys

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, dynamodb-queries, dynamo-local, amazon-dynamodb-index

i'm using serverless framework with dynamodb [in Local].
trying to query with secondary indexed fields. 
goal is to query with few keys like we do in basic find queries in Mongo: `{url:'<Somevalue>'}` or may be like this `{url:<somevalue>,ha:<somevalue>}`

Table config i'm using currently:

**serverless.yml**

```
resources:
  Resources:
    TableName:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      Properties:
        TableName: ${file(./serverless.js):Tables.TableName.name}
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: 'id'
            AttributeType: 'S'
          - AttributeName: 'url'
            AttributeType: 'S'
          - AttributeName: 'ha'
            AttributeType: 'S'
          - AttributeName: 'GSI_1_PK'
            AttributeType: 'S'
          - AttributeName: 'GSI_1_SK'
            AttributeType: 'S'
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: 'id'
            KeyType: 'HASH'
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: 'GSI_1'
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: 'GSI_1_PK'
                KeyType: 'HASH'
              - AttributeName: 'GSI_1_SK'
                KeyType: 'RANGE'
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: 'ALL'
          - IndexName: 'URI_1'
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: 'url'
                KeyType: 'HASH'
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: 'ALL'
          - IndexName: 'HASH_1'
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: 'ha'
                KeyType: 'HASH'
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: 'ALL'

  Outputs:
    TableNameARN:
      Value: { 'Fn::GetAtt': [TableName, Arn] }
      Export:
        Name: ${file(./serverless.js):Exports.TableNameARN}
```

with this, currently i'm only able to search with `id` field,

**Q**:

1> What are the changes needs to be made to query with different fields ? [which is secondary indexed , without using `id` in the query]

2> How do i search with multiple attributes? [i.e : `{url:<somevalue>,ha:<somevalue>}`]

Query i'm using :

```
var params = {
    TableName: '<TableName>',
    IndexName:'URI_1',
    Key: {
      url: 'http://something.com'
    }
};
docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

Output of the query:

```
{
message:"One of the required keys was not given a value",
code:"ValidationException,
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You already used GSI which allows you to use secondary indexes. But you shoud use `query` instead of `get`, it allows you to query any table or secondary index that has a composite primary key (a partition key and a sort key).
- Just use `FilterExpression` and `ExpressionAttributeValues`, it supports u to use multiple conditions.

```html
var params = {
    TableName: '<TableName>',
    IndexName : 'URI_1',
    KeyConditionExpression : 'url = :url',
    FilterExpression : 'ha = :ha',
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
      ':url': 'http://something.com',
      ':ha': 'aaaa'
    }
};
docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data); // successful response
});
```

**additional**

There're three Expressions we could use to query conditions, the first two of them are used for [`Dynamodb.query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property) and the last one is used for [`Dynamodb.updateItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateItem-property) or [`Dynamodb.putItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property):

- KeyConditionExpression - where you need to specify partition key - required - or sort key in. It can only support table key by default, if you want to use Indexes like GSI, you should use it with IndexName.
- FilterExpression - is applied after a Query finishes, but before the results are returned and FilterExpression cannot contain partition key or sort key attributes.
- ConditionExpression - A condition that must be satisfied in order for a conditional update to succeed.

Comment: got the point, but what if i have only the `url` and finding all doc which is having this `url`?

Comment: i'm getting error with `ConditionExpression` so i have used `KeyConditionExpression` , but with this encountered this error: `Query condition missed key schema element `, i'm guessing thats because not passing primary key.

Comment: It works in my case. I haven't found the failed reason yet, it is sure that you already used GSI which allows you to use secondary indexes without Primary Key

Comment: BTW, what's your DynamoDB API version?

Comment: i guess `2012-08-10` , anyways this is working only when i pass `url ` but if i pass `:ha` too as its in the answer right now, its throwing error `Query key condition not supported`

Comment: Updated, try it again, I thought both url and ha were the attributes of URI_1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187778/discussion-between-saikat-chakrabortty-and-troy).